# Ruby logger - when to close logfile

Tags: ruby, logging

Any suggestions when to open and close "Logger" device. I have a main program calling multiple subs via Open4.

1. Should I start a single logger for main and all subs and close when main finishes.
2. Or Open main logger and create a logger for each sub process.

Comment: I think the problem with #1 is coordinating access to the log device so that entries are not jumbled together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choose first option. this is efficient way. because only one instance of Logger can be used every where .